# Is it necessary to migrate from DirectX 9 to DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, directx

I have 3D engines written in DirectX 9 and C++ and everything works like a charm. I would like to know if it is necessary to migrate my code to DirectX 11.

Comment: Necessary for: technical, business, personal learning etc ?  I think this questions Too Broad and should be more focused.

Comment: I'm not aware of any announcement from Microsoft about discontinued support for DirectX 9.0. That would be the the only reason to be forced to update your code. However, you might find a DirectX 11 feature you want to use and migrate anyways.

Comment: @Romen, what better features are available in DirectX 11 and don't exist in DirectX 9?

Comment: [Microsoft has an article for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/understand-direct3d-11-1-concepts) and most of those features would be listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-features) and 11.1 features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-1-features).

Comment: @Romen, what about migrating directly from 9 to 12 instead?

Comment: @Staytuned123, You have to decide for yourself based on the features you require. DirectX is just an API, so DX10, 11, and 12 all share a lot of common functions and types. The cost of moving from DX11 to 12 is less than moving from DX9 to DX 10/11/12 since those newer API versions are much more similar to each other than they are to DX9.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** If it works for you now, that's great. Keep in mind that if it doesn't work for you some day, then you are on your own to figure out how to fix it. Also, you might not be able to fix it.

Direct3D 9 is legacy, and much of the behavior for it is emulated on modern versions of Windows. Most of the debugging facilities and tools for Direct3D are no longer supported, or don't work on modern versions of Windows. The D3DX9 the utility library for Direct3D 9, the Direct3D 9-era HLSL complier, the DirectX SDK itself, and the DirectSetup REDIST are all deprecated. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-), [this blog post](http://aka.ms/dxsdk), and [this one as well](https://aka.ms/dxsetup).

As to *why* you want to move to Direct3D 11, there are plenty of reasons: better supported by the OS, better tested driver codepaths, more robust debugging support and tools, open source utility library support, more predictable hardware behavior, access to latest GPU features, etc. If you want to explore more about it, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/).

See [Important changes from Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/understand-direct3d-11-1-concepts) which is a more modern document, but you may also find the older [Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 10 Considerations (Direct3D 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-d3d9-to-d3d10-considerations) useful as well.

Comment: How about DirectX 11.1 and DirectX 11.2? Can I assume that the latest is the best and simply migrate to DirectX 11.2?

Comment: The details of which exact subversion you use is not that important overall, but it depends on which version of Windows you want to support. DirectX 11.1 or later is supported on Windows 8.0 or later. Partial support for DirectX 11.1 is also available on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 via [KB2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2670838/platform-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1) which at this point is widely deployed. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/).